# Can I default all my strings to C# 6.0 interpolated string concatenation?

Tags: c#, .net, string, concatenation, c#-6.0

I find myself using the C# 6.0 interpolated string concatenation style `$"Hello {name} {lastName}!"` very often in my code.

I understand that when this was introduced, it required a separate syntax to not break any previous strings containing the `{}` symbols. However, when creating new projects I wouldn't mind having to write `{{` or `}}` for those rare occasions I need the actual symbols within my string. Sure it's not much to ask to add an extra `$`, but when I find myself doing it to most of my strings, I'd rather just have it omitted if possible.

I would like `"Hello {name} {lastName}!"` results in `"Hello John Doe" just as $"Hello {name} {lastName}!"` does today.

How can I make the compiler default all strings to be treated as interpolated strings?

Comment: I'm going to assume not, in the same way that `moo(true)` doesn't do the same thing as `if(true)`.

Comment: And instantly make you code unrecognisable for any future time you're posting samples of it containing strings on e.g. Stack Overflow and seeking help? Or for any fellow developers...

Comment: moo(true) for the win

Comment: The only other option I can think of is some kind of extension that would function as a macro to automatically prefix `$` when you open a string with `"`. I'm not aware of anything like that, but I imagine it would be possible to create.

Comment: @John I would love such a macro! Could you point me in the direction of how to create such a macro within visual studio?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot. There currently is no such compiler setting.

Comment: i am up-voting, because i need to use more points for the day, and its a good enough answer for me

Comment: I like that answer too: Short, simple.

Comment: I suspected as much after searching around for it, but not having found any such questions I thought it was worth a short. I guess I'll go suggest this feature in hopes it will be included in some far fetched fantasy future. Thanks!

Comment: @jsmars - it's unlikely to. Having code that you can copy and paste between projects and the compiler *silently* interprets them differently could be a massive source of subtle bugs. Generally, the C# team aim for the "pit of success".

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That's reasonable I guess, I just wish that this had become the default when it was implemented, and have the compiler warm for any strings containing {} for older projects. Sure it's not a big deal, but it does make the code one more bloated unnecessarily.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question and since I couldn't get a solution I came up with a custom visual studio code snippet. It is not a solution to initial question but maybe it helps someone.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>String interpolation</Title>
            <Shortcut>1</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for string interpolation</Description>
            <Author>md</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
                <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>expression</ID>
                    <ToolTip>String interpolation helper</ToolTip>
                    <Function></Function>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[$$"$selected$$end$";]]></Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

This way you can press "1" followed by "TAB" to get `$"";`

Comment: Nice workaround, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can propose an analyzer-fixer to [code-cracker](https://github.com/code-cracker/code-cracker).

You can also search for if with a regular expression: `(?<!\$)"[^"\{]*\{`

Comment: That looks like a very interesting project, I'll have to find some time to read up on how that works to build one of those. Looks like they have a number of other nice-to-haves also. Thanks for the tip!